# TextInputLayout: Remove padding between text and suffixText

Tags: android, material-design, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

Am using `TextInputLayout` in my design for showing price layout. Added `suffixText` for displaying currency symbol which must be shown exactly next to entered text.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/textfield_downpayment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Price Details"
        app:boxBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        android:textColorHint="#ffffff"
        app:suffixTextColor="#ffffff"
        app:suffixText="LE">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:text="1234" />
    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

As of now, suffixText is shown at the end which is not my intended behaviour. Need to remove marked gap between `text` and `suffixText`

[image]

Tried changing `layout_width` to `wrap_content` for `TextInputEditText` which also wraps hint text in `TextInputLayout`.

Comment: Can you post the whole xml file?

Comment: Updated with full layout

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider having the currency symbol under the number? For example, like this:

[image]

If you like this, you just have to replace the suffixText lines, with:

```
app:helperText="LE"
app:helperTextTextColor="@color/black"
```

Comment: But it shows the `helperText` below `TextInputEditText`, I need to show adjacent to text removing gap between `text` and `suffixText`

Comment: From the many examples I've seen, there is now way to do that with suffixText. It is from it's nature to the opposite side. A way I think, is to write the currency symbol inside the Text field: android:text="1234 LE".

Comment: Showing currency symbol inside text field will make it editable, currency symbol needs to be non-editable

Answer (score 0):

You can add **`android:textAlignment="textEnd"`** in your `TextInputEditText`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Price Details"
    app:suffixText="LE">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:textAlignment="textEnd"
        android:text="1234" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]